# How to make jqm buttons behave like regular anchor?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have just started using JQM and I really like how the buttons dynamically load pages and insert their content in a new div to stop the page having to re-render.

I have however come to a point where I need a button to do a proper full page load. How do I get a JQM button to act like a regular anchor yet still have the nice styling?

Comment: read documentation on JQM site or google would have solved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add data-ajax="false"
see more here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

Comment: Or `rel=external` attribute.